# How to explain low grades in a phd interview

Tags: phd, masters, application, interview, grades

I am a recent Masters graduate in nanotechnology and I have applied for a  reputed phd position. I will have an interview very shortly. Unfortunately my Masters grades are very bad and I believe that this will most likely come up as a question in the interview. I would like to know how I can explain those very low grades?

Comment: How can we know why you got bad grades? You were the one who got them, so you need to be the one that knows how to explain them.

Comment: Surely that depends on... well... the *explanation* for the fact that you got low grades? "I was caring for a sick relative", "I have been suffering from a serious medical condition", "I was too lazy to do any work" or "I failed one course and that badly affected my overall grades" may all require different approaches.

Answer (score 8):

*Can* you explain your low grades? If so, give whichever explanation makes you look least bad *and is truthful*. There is no point in beating around the bush here. The grades are on your record and that is that.

The committee must have a reason why they invited you in spite of low grades. Ask yourself: How did I manage to impress the committee and get invited? Rather than come up with a justification for any deficits, I suggest you focus on these strengths. Try to shift the topic of the conversation toward what's positive in your application. You want to be remembered as the one with the awesome project, not as the one with the subpar grades.

Answer (score 0):

From your other question, have you studied in Italy and applying there? If so, I will try to answer with my own take from the country. Remember though:

**We cannot know why you have bad grades. We can only speculate.**

I am going to exclude any serious issues in your life, such as sickness or death in the family or economical hardships that got you to stop caring about grades; if this happened, I am sorry to hear it and I think it is great that you were able to finish your Master's nonetheless; on the other hand, that would be your reason: just tell them you have been through a rough time, so it was a challenge to simply graduate, let alone graduate well.

I bet the most likely reason why you have "bad" (how bad?) grades in Italy is that you accepted your grades no matter what, even when they were low, when you had a chance to refuse them and take the exams again.

- Maybe you did this because you wanted to graduate as quickly as possible and get a headstart in the field as a young graduate.
- maybe you took very difficult classes with strict professors and you did learn the material, but without much luck in the exams.
- Maybe you could not afford to stay in school for too long, so you finished quickly in order to move on with your life.
- Maybe you were just unlucky in a few, "heavy" exams, and the other grades could not raise your GPA back up. This happened to me in my B.Sc. and I was recently asked about it in an interview; in my first year, not wanting to disappoint my family, to drag on my studies, to repeat some exams I did not like, I accepted some bad grades that affected my GPA throughout my B.Sc.

I can only repeat what other people have told you: first of all *be truthful* about it and remember that if your grades had been really THAT bad, you would not have been contacted for an interview. Try to understand why they liked your application enough and play those strengths.